# Function onSelect is faster than click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I use autosuggestion plugin and option onSelect - that option change values to other fields. Everything is fine when I select first time item but when I click on input field with class .auto second time (where already have item) then  fucntion onSelect is faster than function click which give me ID where I need to update field.
This looks like this:

```
function dajjson() {
    $('.auto').click(function () {
        koji = $(this).attr('data-ajdi5');
        console.log(koji);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "autoUsluge.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function (data) {

            $('.auto').autocomplete({

                lookup: data,
                showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                noSuggestionNotice: '<div><a href="#" style="padding:3px; font-weight:bold;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"> + Dodaj novu uslugu</a></div>',
                beforeRender: function (container) {
                    $('.autocomplete-suggestions').append('<div><a href="#" style="padding:3px; font-weight:bold;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"> + Dodaj novu uslugu</a></div>');
                },
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {

                    console.log(koji);
                    $('#cena_' + koji).val(suggestion.cena);
                    console.log(suggestion.cena);
                    $('#jmere' + koji).val(suggestion.jmere);
                    $('#kol' + koji).val(suggestion.kol);
                    $('#popust' + koji).val(suggestion.popust);
                    $('#pdv' + koji).val(suggestion.porez);
                    koji = 0;
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
        }


    });
};
```

So how I can solve problem with function select. How I can get `koji` before onSelect start?

Comment: Have you tried `.mousedown` instead of `.click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the `.change()` event is what you want here.  It will fire after the value has changed.  The `.mousedown()` event will fire even earlier than `.click()`.

Comment: i will try and back in second

Comment: @kaz `click` fires too late for OP, so "even earlier" might very well work for him. Although, if `change` works for him, I agree that would be the better solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. Work great. But how it work faster than onSelect function and click function?

Comment: Its just the order of the events.  .mousedown when you begin the click, .mouseup when the click is released, .click fires after that, and then if the value has changed, .change fires.